# iOS: Vertical Alignment of UIButton in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I need to add vertical alignment for the four buttons, so that it should shift few points below. Below is my code, right now its showing four UIButtons at top of horizontal.

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button1 setTitle:@"CLOTHING" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button2 setTitle:@"ACCESSORIES" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button2.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button3 setTitle:@"FOOTWEAR" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button3.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

UIButton *button4 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
[button4 setTitle:@"GARMENT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button4.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

[self.view addSubview:button1];
[self.view addSubview:button2];
[self.view addSubview:button3];
[self.view addSubview:button4];

NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(button1, button2,button3,button4);
NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-5-[button1]-5-[button2]-5-[button3]-5-[button4]-5-|"
                                                                         options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];

// Find the equal width constraint and set priority to high (750)
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in horizontalConstraints) {
    if (constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth) {
        constraint.priority = UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh;
    }
}

[self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
```

[image]

Comment: translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints is set to No but no vertical constraints are given.I guess it considers only the horizontal constraint with all buttons aligned centre to y.Hence it starts from the top edge of screen.Have you tried with Top layout constraint.

Comment: Yeah but didn't work, I have given vertical constraints in same line, however it crash.

Comment: Just to get more clarification,have you given top layout constraint to all buttons and added only horizontal constraint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving a horizontal constraint Change your constraint with this

```
  NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-15-[button1]-5-[button2]-5-[button3]-5-[button4]"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:views];
```